# Proof of Convergence - Absolute value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n= a$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n= 0$, prove that for all ${b_n}$ such that $\forall n\in\mathbb N,|a_n - b_n| < c_n$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=a$.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to M.SE. So what have you tried and what are your thoughts on the problem? Please add these to your post so that people can give help that's *relevant* to you.

Answer (score 0):

We show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=a$.

So we need to show that for every positive $\epsilon\gt 0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $|b_n-a|\lt \epsilon$ whenever $n\gt N$.

We know that there exists $N_1$ such that if $n\gt N_1$, then $|a_n-a|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

We also know that there exists $N_2$ such that if $n\gt N_2$ then $|c_n|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Let $N=\max(N_1, N_2)$. If $n\gt N$ then $|a_n-a|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $|a_n-b_n|\lt |c_n|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Thus by the Triangle Inequality, if $n\gt N$ then $|b_n-a|\le |a_n-a|+|b_n-a_n|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

**Remark:** We gave a quite formal proof, which may at first sight look mysterious. However, the geometric idea is quite simple. After a while, $a_n$ is real close to $a$. And after a while, $a_n-b_n$ is real close to $0$. So $b_n$ is real close to $a$.